# RemoteApps on Server 2012 and above in a workgroup environment

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I was able to set up RemoteApps on Server 2008 R2 on AWS in a workgroup environment. I want to do the same on Server 2012 and above. I understand that Microsoft removed RemoteApp manager when a Server 2012 is in a workgroup environment and it seems the server must be joined to a domain before RemoteApp manager becomes available. Also, they removed old Powershell commands and the new ones only work in a domain environment. Is there another way I can still setup up RemoteApps on a Server 2012 and above in a workgroup environment ?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

My setup is Windows Server 2012 R2 + workgroup + Remote Desktop Services role (with 2 sub-roles: session host and rd licensing). Like you, I could not publish programs as RemoteApps, until I found this free little tool: http://www.kimknight.net/remoteapptool

As of now, it doesn't support Windows Server 2016 but this might change in the future. Also, I had no idea you can "remote-app" programs hosted in Windows XP SP3! :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, however, it seems the site link http://www.kimknight.net/remoteapptool is broken

Comment: @Mindaugas  I think that another way of running remoteApps (without any external tool) would be to use **gpedit.msc** and set the policy _Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Connections\Allow remote start of unlisted programs_. And then put full program path into the *.rdp file to be used by clients. Of course, this way is worse for security.  And another thing, before installing a new program, don't forget to issue **change user /install** and then **change user /execute** when you're done installing.

Comment: I will have to take a look at it when I get a chance. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I got my Remote App running on a Windows Server 2016 that's not joined to a domain. The idea was provided by lisz's comment to the other suggested solution. This did the trick for me:

- Enable *Remote Desktop Session Host* and *Remote Desktop Licensing* on the server
- Run `gpedit.msc` and enable this group policy: Computer Configuration > Adminstrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Connections > **Allow remote start of unlisted programs**
- create a custom *.rdp file that contains the full program path: `remoteapplicationprogram:s:C:\path\to\application.exe`

As lisz pointed out in her comment, allowing the start of unlisted programs can be a security concern. So this solution might not be suited for everyone.

I hope this helps someone in a similar situation!